# Load Kendo UI Grid according to the sort order(DESC/ASCE) of a column using JSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, kendo-ui

In my ASP.NET MVC Application, I am using Kendo UI Grid and binding data through JSON. For the First time when my grid gets rendered I want to display sorted data on the basis of one column. What attribute of JSON Grid View do I need to add in my data so that Grid will display whole data based on the order(ascending/descending) of a sorted column. Can someone please share the code for default sorting implementation on the basis of one column for JSON data.